# Performing Segue to a new viewcontroller - prepare for segue fails swift 5

Tags: segue, uistoryboardsegue, iboutlet, swift5, xcode11

I'm trying to perform a `segue` to another `UIViewController`.

I wish to pass data to that new controller. However, looks like the `UILabels` of the new `UIViewController` are not yet initialised, so I'm an error which states that I'm unwrapping a nil-value optional.

What am I missing?

Here's my code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "addProductSegue", sender: cell)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if let nextViewController = segue.destination as? AddProductsViewController
    {
        let productCell = sender as! ProductCell

        nextViewController.productName!.text = productCell.product!.Name
        nextViewController.priceForKg!.text = "\(productCell.product?.priceForKg ?? 0.0)"
        nextViewController.productImage!.image = productCell.productImageView.image
    }
}
```

And the new `UIViewController`:

```
import UIKit

class AddProductsViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var productName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceForKg: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productImage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func addProduct(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create separate values for each of the elements you wish to add and then use them in the second view controller

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "addProductSegue", sender: cell)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{
    if let nextViewController = segue.destination as? AddProductsViewController
    {
        let productCell = sender as! ProductCell

        nextViewController.productNameText = productCell.product!.Name
        nextViewController.priceForKgText = "\(productCell.product?.priceForKg ?? 0.0)"
        nextViewController.productImageImage = productCell.productImageView.image
    }
}
```

And in the second ViewController have:

```swift
import UIKit

class AddProductsViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var productName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceForKg: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var productImage: UIImageView!
//The elements you will reference in your prepare for segue
    var productNameText = ""
    var priceForKgText = ""
    var productImageImage : UIImage?
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
//Call the function
        setupViews() 
    }

    func setupViews(){ //create a function that handles the ui update once the objects are initialized
     productName.text = productNameText
     priceForKg.text = priceForKgText
     guard let image = productImageImage else {
     return
     }
     productImage.image = image
    }

    @IBAction func addProduct(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```